# Calling setcontentview by a framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am very new to android development, so the answer may be very simple.

I am using this library in my project, 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

I have my main layout(activity_main) which has a surface view that shows the camera. This library uses a layout file (menu_frame). My problem is that I want to overlay that layout file on top of my layout (activity_main). So that instead of the menu (menu_frame) pushing my layout file, it would overlay it and leave my layout file in place.

The purpose, is that I want to set the opacity of the menu to a minimum so that while the menu is open you can still view the camera behind it.

I call my setcontentview(R.layout.activity_main) and then I call setbehindcontentview(R.layout.menu_frame). So I thought if I gave the menu an id and add the framelayout in the menu_frame layout to my activity_main layout, I would be able to call setbehindcontentview(R.id.framelayoutId), but that doesn't work.

Here is a snipit of my code:

```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


       final int activity = R.layout.activity_main;
       setContentView(activity);

       setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The menu_frame.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

To sum up, I want one layout file to overlay another layout file, or combining both in a way that would overlay them on top of eachother.

Thanks in advance